# Не могу зайти в Gitlab установленный на локальном хосте

Tags: gitlab

На локальном хосте (Linux) установлен Gitlab, работает чуть больше месяца. Было создано только два пользователя root и alex.
Сегодня пробую зайти в него и меня перенаправляет на страницу авторизации. И ни под одним из пользователей я не могу зайти, пишет, что не верный пароль.
Попробовал сделать сброс

```
gitlab-rake "gitlab:password:reset[alex]"
gitlab-rake "gitlab:password:reset[root]"
```

На обе команды так же получил одинаковое сообщение

```
Unable to find user with username
```

Если запустить
sudo gitlab-ctl status
то видно, что все сервисы запущены.

Пробую найти пользователя root через Rails console:

```
user = User.find_by_username 'root'
```

в ответ получаю

```
nil
```

Как мне восстановить доступ?

Comment: Вспоминайте, что делали до этого. Обновлялся, бекапы делали

Comment: бэкапы точно нет, обновление  прилетало, но я его отклонил. Настройки тоже ни какие не менял. Такое чувство что кто-то потер моих пользователей

Comment: чудес не бывает. Что то произошло, это надо выявить. Я бы ещё в логах поковырялся, я так понимаю, они Вам доступны.

Comment: логи смотрел, особого криминала не нашел, но правда там их дофига и что искать толком я не знаю. Я с этим гитлабом первый раз работаю